# How to support my flutter app for 64 bit devices?

Tags: android, flutter

I am new in flutter. I have created one release build of my app.

This build work for 32bit devices but not for 64bit devices.

Please help me to where and how to change the settings/configuration.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18494#issuecomment-477502287

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your build.gradle app module like this -

```
// Your app's build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.app'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 27
   defaultConfig {
       appId "com.google.example.64bit"
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 28
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, since flutter `1.7.8+hotfix.2` this is already done by default.

So, currently, running `flutter build apk` as usual will generate a 'fat APK' containing android-arm and android-arm64 binaries.

```
$ flutter build apk

You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64.

Initializing gradle...                                              0.7s
Resolving dependencies...                                           1.6s
[...]
```